# dynamic name for an input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with automatic name for input, I'll try to explain what i need to do. i have an id, that I get it from an external function. I need to use this numeric id to create another function like that.

```
var id = 10;  // this is the id (from external function)
var value = "n"+bar.toString(); // (I try to cast the id as string) 
$("input[name="+value+"]").on('change', function() { // use the cast value to name my input.
  alert($("input[name="+value+"]:checked", "#myForm").val()); 
});
```

When I try to do that I get `undefined`, but when I change the id like that `var id ="10"` I get the correct answer, but I have a numeric input. Please help me figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: i did't see you cast the id to string. `bar.toString();` should be `id.toString(); `and what is `n` for??

Comment: Here, 'n' refers to...?

Comment: my inputs are like that : n10  , n20 .... its just a name

Comment: then use id.toString();

Comment: id.toString() is not working i still get undefined

Comment: value as undefined ?

Comment: How about var value = "n" + 10; There's no need to do toString()

Comment: `toString` is not needed here.  Numbers are automatically cast to strings when concatenating with strings.

Comment: non of thoses answers seem to be working , i get undefined when i check the radiobox with name n10  ,  but when i do  "n10" all at one i get the correct value

Comment: If the `value` is `undefined`, you may be clicking on a checkbox which is not in the context of `#myForm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want something like this? This is based on an assumption that you have checkboxes within a form!

```js
var ids = [10, 20, 30, 11, 12];
$.each(ids, function(index, val) {
    var id = val;
    var value = "n" + id; // `.toString` is not required!
    $("#myForm").find("input[name='"+value+"']").on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            alert( $(this).val() );
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="n10" value="10" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="n11" value="11" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="n12" value="12" />
</form>
```

Comment: can u use that inside a loop and show it to me , for exemple array {10,20,30} and iterate all the code and each time put the value in id and see if you can manage handle all the checkboxes ?

Comment: Edited my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

use this code no need for id.toString()

```
var id = getId();  // this is the id (from externel function)
var value = "n" + id;
$("input[name="+value+"]").on('change', function() {
    alert($("input[name="+value+"]:checked").val());  //change this selector accordingly
});

function getId() {
    return 10;
}
```

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/rrehan/srhjwrz4/) is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rrehan/srhjwrz4/

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
var id = 10;  // this is the id (from externel function)
              var value = id.toString(); // (i try to cast the id as string) 
            console.log(value);
            $("input[name="+value+"]").on('change', function() { // use the casted value to name my input.
                  alert($("input[name="+value+"]:checked", "#myForm").val()); 
                });
```

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/x6tfaky4/1/)

Comment: i am using a loop i guess this why i have this problem ? no ? the externel ids are genereted from an array could this be the problem